# Django excluding specific instances from queryset without using field lookup

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset

I sometimes have the need to make sure some instances are excluded from a queryset.
This is the way I do it usually:

```
unwanted_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=bad_luck_number)
uninteresting_stuff_happens()
my_results = MyModel.objects.exclude(id=unwanted_instance.id)
```

or, if I have more of them:

```
my_results = MyModel.objects.exclude(id_in=[uw_in1.id, uw_in2.id, uw_in3.id])
```

This 'feels' a bit clunky, so I tried:

```
my_ideally_obtained_results = MyModel.objects.exclude(unwanted_instance)
```

Which doesn't work. But I read [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637897/django-queryset-excluding-entries-in-second-model/1638163#1638163) that a subquery can be used as parameter for exclude.
Am I out of luck? Am I missing some functionality (checked the docs, but didn't find any useful pointer)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The way you're already doing it is the best way.

If it's a model-agnostic way of doing this you're looking for, don't forget that you can do `query.exclude(pk=instance.pk)`.

Just as an aside, *if* Django's ORM had an identity mapper (which it doesn't at present), then you would be able to do something like `MyModel.objects.filter(<query>).all().remove(<instance>)`, but you're out of luck in that regard. The way you're doing it (or the one above) is the best you've got.

Oh, and also you can do much better than that `in` query with a list comprehension: `query.exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in <unwanted objects>])`

Comment: Also, if you have the queryset to exclude (e.g. `MyModel.objects.filter(<exclude-query>)`), you can get the ids using a `ValuesQuerySet` like so:
`id_dicts = MyModel.objects.filter(<exclude-query>).values('id')` and then
`query.exclude(id__in=[item['id'] for item in id_dicts])`.

Comment: I just wanted to add something to @RacingTadpole's suggestion: You can easily use `values_list( "id", flat = True )` to get a sequential list of all IDs. This will however hit the DB, so I'd suggest using Python's list comprehension.

Answer (score 8):

The Given answer is perfect and try this which works fine for me

step 1)

```
 from django.db.models import Q
```

step 2)

```
 MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=[o.id for o in <unwanted objects>]))
```

Comment: How is using a `Q` expression better than `.exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in <unwanted objects>])`?

Comment: this is one more alternative solution to achieve the same

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient alternative.

Comment: This works well in a scenario like `blocks = self.blocks.filter(~Q(image='') | Q(~Q(video='') & Q(loop=True)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can put your unwanted items in a list , and a fetch all items except those in the list like so:

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(id__in=[id1,id2,id3 ])
```

Comment: this was explicitly stated in the question as one of the things I tried. I was looking for alternative solutions!