# Exclude by object in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to exclude some objects from my queryset and was wondering how can I pass a list of objects to Django's `exclude()`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
pages = [page1, page2] # page1 and page2 are Page objects
Page.objects.filter(site=site).exclude(pages)
```

I can do a `exclude(pk__in=[p.pk for p in pages])` but it doesn't feel natural. How can I specify a list of objects to be excluded from the above queryset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django excluding specific instances from queryset without using field lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032104/django-excluding-specific-instances-from-queryset-without-using-field-lookup)

Comment: I agree that it does not feel natural, but I am afraid that's how it works!

Comment: I thought there would be some other approach to this. Thank you!

Comment: If pages is a queryset itself then you either work to make a single query or Page.objects.filter(site=site).exclude(pk__in = pages.values_list('pk', flat=True))

Comment: No, it is not a queryset, it is just a list of `Page` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that my approach is one of the best, so far. Here's what I've ended up with:

```
pages = [page1, page2] # page1 and page2 are Page objects
Page.objects.filter(site=site).exclude(pk__in=[p.pk for p in pages])
```