# How do I remove an item from Queryset while iterating?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following:

```
jobs = Task.objects.filter(created__month=month, created__year=year)

for job in jobs:
    try:
        _ = User.all_objects.filter(user=job.creator_id, customer=job.customer_id).reverse()[0]
    except IndexError:
        # Remove this job
        job.delete()  # This is deleting object from the Database which I don't want to happen. 
        # I'm looking for a method such as jobs.remove(job)
```

From above, I don't know if it is possible to use 'exclude' in my 1st query. That's why I'm wondering if there's a way to remove 'job' from Queryset.

Comment: It is hard to guess what you are intending to do. If you just want to skip the job that raises an `IndexError` an continue with the next one, just use the `continue` statement. If you want to filter the list in python, use a list comprehension with `if`. If you want to do something else, give a better problem description.

Answer (score 2):

The main appeal of a `QuerySet` is that it's lazy, but you are evaluating everything no matter what, so I don't think you'd lose anything if you just made it a list with a list comprehension.

```
jobs = [j for j in jobs if  User.all_objects.filter(user=job.creator_id, customer=job.customer_id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do `delete` in one shot. Just collect all job ids you need first:

```
jobs = Task.objects.filter(created__month=month, created__year=year)

to_be_deleted = []
for job in jobs:
    if not User.all_objects.filter(user=job.creator_id, 
                                   customer=job.customer_id).exists():
    to_be_deleted.append(job.id)

jobs.filter(id__in=to_be_deleted).delete()
```

ps: I don't quite understand why do you have `reverse()[0]`, but it's essentially the same as checking if queryset has values or not. `reverse` is not free and will hurt your performance, same thing with slicing and dicing. Just use `exists()` would be better.

Comment: That will actually delete the objects from the database, which the person who makes the question explicitly said doesn't want to.

Comment: I think there is a better answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032479/515093